# calling a function from a form into a module

Tags: vb.net

I have a an array in my module, so I want to display the contents of my array in a form textbox, here is my array

```
Module Module1
    Sub AddCourse()
        Dim Subjects() = {"Ms Office 2007", "internet and commmunications", "Lifetime skills"}
        For i = 0 To UBound(Subjects) ' FOR LOOP TO WRITE AN ARRAY
            i = i +1
            Subjects(i) 
        Next
        txtComputer.Text = subjects()
```

my problem is, when I try to use my texbox txtComputer in my module I get an error.

My question is, how do I make a form textbox to be used in a module

I get an error that reads "Error'txtComputer' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."

My question is based on, how do I get this error fixed?

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving??

Comment: What is the error you got...? what is the name of your Window form..?

Comment: Why are you using the FOR Loop? You array is initialized by the line before.

Comment: I think the Textbox is in the windows form and you are using that in Module with our Reference... just Try like this... FormName.txtComputer.Text = subjects.. it will work...

Answer (score 1):

There are several suggestions I have for you.

First, don't use `UBound`.  That's an old VB6 function that is only provided for backwards compatability.  You should instead use `Subjects.Length`.

Next, when you're incrementing the `i` variable, you don't need to say `i = i + 1`.  You can just use the `+=` operator for that (e.g. `i += 1`).

However, you shouldn't be explicitly incrementing `i` inside your `For` loop, anyway.  The loop automatically increments the variable for you each time it iterates through the loop.  If you do it explicitly yourself inside the loop, like that, it will skip every other item.

Next, in this case, you really should just use a `For Each` loop, rather than an iterator:

```
For Each subject As String in Subjects
    '...
Next
```

Next, you aren't actually concatenating the items together inside you loop.  You should be doing something like this:

```
For Each subject As String in Subjects
    txtComputer.Text += subject
Next
```

However, in that case, for efficiency sake, you really ought to use a `StringBuilder`, like this:

```
Dim builder As New StringBuilder()
For Each subject As String in Subjects
    builder.Append(subject)
Next
txtComputer.Text = builder.ToString()
```

But, all of this is moot because all you really need to do is to call `String.Join`:

```
txtComputer.Text = String.Join(", ", Subject)
```

As far as why you can't access the text box from the module, that is because the module is a separate object, so the text box is entirely out of scope.  For instance, what if you had two instances of your form displayed at the same time?  How in the world would this module know which form's text box you were referring to?  The simplest way to correct that would be to pass a reference to your form into the module's method, like this:

```
Module Module1
    Sub AddCourse(f As MyFormName)
        f.txtComputer.Text = "Hello world"
    End Sub
End Module
```

And then you could call it from the form, like this:

```
AddCourse(Me)
```

However, that would be exceptionally bad practice.  Ideally, nothing outside of the form's code should ever deal directly with any of the controls on the form.  So, the far better way to do it would be to simply have the method return the data, and then have the form set it's own control to the data that is returned, for instance:

```
Module Module1
    Function GetCourse() As String
        Return "Hello world"
    End Function
End Module
```

And then call it from the form like this:

```
txtComputer.Text = GetCourse()
```

Comment: actually my loop is working, and what what I inclused as a loop is an example.

Comment: Ok, In the future, please post valid code and be more specific rather than leading everyone in the wrong direction.  I've updated my answer to show how to do that from a module.  Let me know if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.Join` to create a string which separates each subject with `Environment.NewLine`:

```
txtComputer.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Subjects)
```

The problem with your for loop is that it makes no sense at all since you have already declared **and** initialized the array in one line.

If you want to use a loop anyway, you can use a `StringBuilder` to concat all strings together:

```
Dim subjectBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder
For Each subject In Subjects
    subjectBuilder.Append(subject).Append(Environment.NewLine)
Next
If subjectBuilder.Length <> 0 Then subjectBuilder.Length -= Environment.NewLine.Length
txtComputer.Text = subjectBuilder.ToString()
```

Comment: I don't worry much about the array, my main worry is the message that reds "Error 'txtComputer' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level." How do I solve this?

Comment: @TSHUKELAGEORGE: Why do you need to use a `Module` instead of a `Class` at all? You should also return the text ferom a method, the  you can call this method/function from your form and assign the text to the `Text` property of the `TextBox`.